# nextcloud snap with data-directory on external harddrive

Tags: snap, nextcloud

I installed nextcloud on my raspberrypi 3 using [this link](https://flexion.org/posts/2016-12-raspberry-pi-3-powered-nextcloud-box-on-ubuntu-core/). Everything is working pretty well except I don't like the UX of having all the extra storage space coming from the "External Storage" add-in, since it means that everyone now has to know to put all of their files in a designated folder.

It seems like I should just be able to tell nextcloud to use the external harddrive as the data-directory location (without the external storage add-in) and all will be well and good... and it seems like in theory that works fine. But, since it's installed as a snap, it seems like the snap doesn't have access to that part of my filesystem and thus it doesn't work.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions. Should I mount the harddrive inside the snap's writable area? Is it possible to give the snap access to the harddrive?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A bug was logged against the Nextloud snap for this issue, with the solution given [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/150#issuecomment-267641192). It's now a [wiki entry](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Change-data-directory-to-use-another-disk-partition) as well.

To quickly summarize here: you're right, this should be possible, and it is. However, by default the Nextcloud snap doesn't have permission to access removable media (as mentioned in its [README](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use)).

So, the steps given are:

1. Connect the `removable-media` plug: `sudo snap connect nextcloud:removable-media`.
2. Connecting that interface gives Nextcloud permission to access things in `/media/`, so you can edit `/var/snap/nextcloud/current/nextcloud/config/config.php` and make sure the `datadirectory` is pointing to the right place.
3. Disable the snap: `sudo snap disable nextcloud`
4. Move (or copy) the current data directory to the new location: `sudo mv /var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/data /media/my/new/data`.
5. Re-enable the snap: `sudo snap enable nextcloud`.

Now you don't need to bother with the external media solution: all of Nextcloud's data will be there.

Note that this only covers the raw data (e.g. files) hosted by Nextcloud. The database and apps are still in `/var/snap/nextcloud/current/`. I suggest you leave them there.

**Note**: if you have issues with the Nextcloud snap, you can [log a bug against it](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues).

Comment: This worked great! I swear, I did do a decent amount of searching and did not find your linked post. The connect ... removable-media is the piece I didn't know about; that's exactly what I was looking for and very helpful. It seems like a good entry for the snapcraft faq. Apologies for posting this in the wrong spot. Placing a bug report seemed silly when I didn't actually find a bug.

Comment: Oh no apology necessary! This should really be covered in the Nextcloud snap's README, or perhaps its wiki.

Comment: Another thing to mention here is that there could be a permission issue on files as nextcloud server still runs as root, while we might want to use other permissions to files (I'm using nextcloud as a `syncthing` front-end). To fix this, initially I was using the trick of adding an `sftp` storage pointing to the server itself and accessing as the wanted user so using `127.0.0.1` as host and the file owner as the user with a generated ssh key. But this wasn't the best choice. Using `bindfs` instead with something like `bindfs --map=ubuntu/root:@ubuntu/@root`, does instead the wanted job.

Comment: After I move the directory I got "UniqueConstraintViolationException\",\"Message\":\"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `oc_filecache`...". I hadn't added any files to it, just a clean install of the snap, created the admin users and one login before moving the directory. Any clue?

Comment: nextcloud snap + syncthing - bindfs entry in fstab is only sustainable way I made this work. Nextcloud snap not using the permissions of the actual user is painful.

Comment: i noticed that the current folder is symlink to the current version of the nextcloud, what happens when we update nextcloud? Do we have to redo this again?

Comment: Don't worry Major, when the snap is updated the new version runs against the edit you already made (the data is copied). You won't need to do this again.

Comment: I had permission issues, where nextcloud requires the datadiractory to have permission 0770. To change the permission: https://askubuntu.com/a/91054/514666

Answer (score 4):

Use 'stop' instead of 'disable' otherwise you won't be able to edit config.php.

1. Enable external storage for snap:
   sudo snap connect nextcloud:removable-media
2. Stop nexcloud snap:
   sudo snap stop nextcloud
3. Update storage location:
   sudo vim /var/snap/nextcloud/current/nextcloud/config/config.php

change data location:

'datadirectory' => '/media/storage/data',

4. Move the data directory to the storage device:
   sudo mv /var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/data /media/storage/
5. Start nextcloud snap:
   sudo snap start nextcloud